# Is it better to define methods as static?

Tags: c#, static, static-methods

Is there a memory or performance difference to define and use methods statically instead of using methods inside of instantiated classes?  Does the method itself hog memory with each instance of the class, when the method is not static?

Perhaps any variables declared in the static method would be un-threadsafe?

```
/// <summary>
/// A class using instance methods (non-static)
/// </summary>
public class Junk
{
    public int x {get; protected set;}
    public Junk(int x = 0)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void Increment()
    {
        this.x++;
    }
}
```

versus

```
/// <summary>
/// A class using static methods
/// </summary>
public class Junk
{
    public int x {get; protected set;}
    public Junk(int x = 0)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public static void Increment(Junk thisJunk)
    {
        thisJunk.x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Come on.  Within 5 seconds of posting this question, somebody votes it down.  Seriously?  What the heck.  Please don't down-vote questions unless they're miscategorized or something else fundamentally wrong with the question.  And certainly don't down-vote without posting a comment explaining why you down-voted.

Comment: From your link: “Use your downvotes whenever you encounter a […] no-effort-expended post”. Well, did you do some research about the issue? If you did, your question doesn't show it. (I didn't downvote your question, but I can see why someone would.)

Comment: If you search for C# static method memory, or performance, it's basically just too vague, and all the results don't answer the question. So yes, I read several stackoverflow questions, as well as google results, as well as a few MSDN pages before posting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; instance methods do not take up any space per-instance. Even virtual methods don't do that - there is only one method table that is used by all instances.

That said, there is a very minor performance difference: instance methods take the `this` reference as a hidden parameter, and the callsite may need to check for null references. This makes calling the method slightly more expensive, but the difference almost never matters.

Although in your example, I highly suspect the JIT compiler will inline the method (whether it is static or not) and generate identical code either way.

Answer (score 7):

There's no difference. As your example shows, an instance method is logically nothing more than a static method where the first parameter is named "this". The only difference is that "this" is automatically checked for nullity in an instance method; it is not in a static method.

Now, *virtual* methods do cause a performance cost because the method that is actually invoked must be computed at runtime, not at compile time. That can add up to several nanoseconds to the runtime of your program, and it also precludes certain optimizations, such as inlining.

As for thread safety: whether a variable is used safely or not is a property of *the entire program*, not a property of whether a method is static or not.

Comment: If a variable is declared *inside* a method, and then the method gets called by multiple threads, I would expect each thread to instantiate those variables independently of each other, and they're scoped to within the method.  So the comment about "the entire program" seems to be non-applicable, unless I'm wrong somehow.

Comment: In other words, when I asked about variables declared inside a static method perhaps being un-threadsafe, I wanted to make sure that declaring a method as static doesn't implicitly mean all of its local variables are static too.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey: The property that makes a local variable *local* is that it can only be accessed by name in a local scope. There are plenty of ways in C# for a local variable to represent storage that can be accessed by multiple threads. The locals in an iterator block, a lambda, or in an async method can all be accessed on multiple threads.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey: And FYI, C# does not support the notion of a 'static local' like C++ does. I've always considered that to be a minor deficiency of the language.

Comment: How about this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245046%28v=vs.80%29.aspx ? C# generates "callvirt" IL instruction on all instance method calls, except for parent calls. So first argument null check should represent additional work for processor. However my tests show consistent results, where static version with explicit instance parameter to be slower in optimized version of JITed code! It even happens sometimes in static version without instance parameter!

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared in a static method are definitely not static. See ex, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/05/11/why-doesn-t-c-support-static-method-variables.aspx.

Here's a more recent FAQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx : "C# does not support static local variables (variables that are declared in method scope)."

Comment: Wow, somebody's really a fan of downvoting here.  How irritating.  This answer, while not a complete answer to the question, does indeed add useful and relevant information, so I upvoted to at least neutralize the downvote.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your comments in reply to Eric Lippert and thought it would be useful. SO can be an arbitrary and obliquely punative place sometimes -- you get used to it, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods and instance methods are not interchangeable.  They are used in entirely different situations to solve completely different problems.  You should use whichever type of method is appropriate for what you want to do.

Since you won't be in a position where either type of method would be appropriate for the task at hand the performance differences (if any) between the two types of methods is irrelevant.  You should do what is logically and semantically appropriate for your program.